# Ajax result from Codigniter is the whole HTML page instead of just the data

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

When I do `console.log(data);` to get the Ajax result data, I get the whole page source instead of just the results, although the results appear inside the search form div (only in the returned data)

How do 
I get only the data?

This is the view:

```
<div id="form-all">    

    <form name="search" action="html_form_action.asp" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="search" />
    <input type="submit" value="חפש" />
    </form>

</div>

<script>

    $("form[0] :submit").live("click", function(event) {

        event.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({

            type: "POST",
            url: "<?= site_url('pages/search') ?>",
            data: {company : $("form[0] :text").val()},
            success: function(data) {

                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    });

</script>
```

And this is the controller:

```
function search1()
{
    $data['page_title'] = 'Search';

    $this->load->view('head', $data);
    $this->load->view('pages/search', $data);
    $this->load->view('footer');

    return json_encode($this->Company->get_companies_by_name($this->input->post('company')));
}
```

Comment: What happens if you only echo the results with out the header/footer view?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. That is correct.

The data property of a jQuery AJAX request has nothing to do with the return value -- that is solely the responsibility of whatever the server sends combined with whatever happens in the success method. You will need to do some refactoring.

If it were me, I would consider this:

```
function ajax_search()
{
    echo json_encode(
         $this->Company->get_companies_by_name(
             $this->input->post('company')
         )->result());
}
```

And then in jQuery, simply change it to:

```
    event.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({

        type: "POST",
        url: "<?= site_url('pages/ajax_search') ?>",
        data: {company : $("form[0] :text").val()},
        success: function(data) {

            console.log(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: it works! but now I get this which I have no idea what it is... `{"conn_id":null,"result_id":null,"result_array":[],"result_object":[],"custom_result_object":[],"current_row":0,"num_rows":2,"row_data":null}`

Comment: Ah. That is a representation of a CI query object see update above.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
data: {"company" : $("form[0] :text").val()},
```